# MathJax render issue

Tags: wordpress, mathjax

I'm using MathJax in my wordpress blog, but I'm getting some weird stuff:

[image: example]

The code I used was `$0.\overline{9} = 1$`. Is something I did wrong or just a bug from MathJax?

Comment: If you use the MathJax contextual menu to view the math as TeX code, do you see a space (or anything else) between `\over` and `line`?  It looks like the macro is being interpreted as `\over line` rather than `\overline`.  Can you post a link to the blog page?

Comment: There's nothing between \over and line. Here's the link http://jmorais.com/99-999-dos-matematicos-concordam-0-999-1/

Comment: As you mention below, it turns out that your hyphenation javascript is inserting invisible characters, so there actually *is* something there (you just can't see it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Hyphenator and sometimes it tries to hyphenize the tex code before it can be rendered by MathJax. Including the following code in mathjax configuration solves the problem.

```
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
  MathJax.InputJax.TeX.prefilterHooks.Add(function (data) {
    data.math = data.math.replace(/\u00AD/g,"");
  });
});
```

The code tells to mathjax to ignore the hyphen character.

Comment: See the [MathJax issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/341) where this solution was proposed for more details.